# nfs mounts over wrong subnet when another mount happens first

Tags: nfs, subnet, autofs

I have a weird issue with an NFS server and clients that are connected over two separate private subnets.

The private subnets are 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0 and 10.2.0.0/255.255.0.0 addressed as .local and .qlogic respectively (DNS is served by 10.1.1.1, names all resolving as expected)

Address of machines are identical in the last pair of numbers, so 10.1.1.1 is also 10.2.1.1 and so on.

The reason for this is a somewhat heterogeneous environment (not all clients are on the 10.2 subnet and all are on 10.1, but 10.2 is much faster than 10.1 - this is also why one mount is exported twice including a 'slow' version)

exportfs on the server returns the relevant lines

```
/export/apps 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0
/export/data    10.2.0.0/255.255.0.0
/export/data    10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

auto.share on the client includes

```
apps server.local:/export/&
data server.qlogic:/export/&
data_slow server.local:/export/data
```

If I mount /share/apps and then /share/data I get the following output from 'mount':

```
server.local:/export/apps on /share/apps type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.1.255.240,local_lock=none,addr=10.1.1.1)
server.qlogic:/export/data on /share/data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.1.255.240,local_lock=none,addr=10.1.1.1)
```

Note that /share/data has wrongly been put over the 10.1.0.0 network.

If I unmount them and mount them in the order /share/data then /share/apps I get this:

```
server.qlogic:/export/data on /share/data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.2.255.240,local_lock=none,addr=10.2.1.1)
server.local:/export/apps on /share/apps type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.1.1.1,mountvers=3,mountport=20048,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.1.1.1)
```

Now /share/data is correctly over 10.2.0.0, but weirdly /share/apps is now using NFS version 3.

I'm only really bothered about /share/data always going over 10.2 and less bothered about the NFS version, but this has me baffled.

Other useful information - non-NFS traffic seems to behave exactly as expected.